# Cambiar apariencia de una web

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html5, css

Estoy realizando una web con php , html5 , css3 y javascript.

En mi codigo de html con php tengo diferentes div los cuales tienen diferentes colores y el texto que aparece en ellos tiene distintas familias las letras.
Quisiera poder realizar un apartado en la web en la cual configuraramos esa apariencia de los div, cambiarlos los colores y la familia de las letras y que se guardara la configuracion editada.

Como se podria realizar lo que deseo hacer con javascript o jquery

Comment: Las preguntas hay que formuilarlas correctamente. Quieres otro estilo, o quieres que al interactuar cambie el estilo.
Si es lo primero, deberías hacerlo con CSS. Lo típico es crear clases en css y utilizarlas en el html.
Si es interactuando, dependiendo que se busque, te valdrá con css o jquery

Comment: quiero un estilo nuevo , es decir , segun lo que elija el usuario camie la apariencia de la pagina y se almacene para futuras iteraciones con la pagina